# Как сделать защиту от скам ссылок нитро?

Tags: discord.py

У меня есть сервер, и я хочу сделать проверку на скам ссылки нитро, ибо добавлять каждый раз домен это не вариант, но я не знаю как реализовать это кодом

Comment: был уже подобный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64265189/is-there-a-way-for-a-discord-bot-to-check-if-a-discord-nitro-gift-code-is-valid

Comment: Это проверка на валидность нитро, а мне надо чтобы не подарочный код блокировало а недействительну ссылку нитро, по типу **скам нитро в стим**

Comment: Проанализируйте задачу. Допустим, спам всегда идет массово, на все доступные каналы, от одного человека, одно сообщение. Вот и пытайтесь обнаружить это поведение. То есть, "Если текст сообщения пользователя == предыдущий текст сообщения пользователя **и** время между ними <N ms **и** каналы разные **то** смело можно банить". Еще можно для уверенности проверять наличие ссылки, добавив условие "**и** есть ссылка в сообщение". Нормальный человек не будет спамить одним и тем же текстом во все каналы, в течении пары милисек., это всегда боты.

Comment: А что если это окажется обычный человек?

Comment: Ну найдите мне человека, который за пол секунды напишет одно и тоже сообщение на 10 каналов, после этого поговорим про это) Даже копипастом у него займет это больше времени. Да и если попадет под этот фильтр, то значит человек сам занимается спамом и его тоже стоит забанить. Ведь одно и тоже сообщени на тех же 10 каналах это и есть ведь спам...

Comment: Напишите это как ответ) И я отмечу решением, так будет лучше

Comment: Если хотел бы, то уже написал) Можете оформить сами это ответом, а лучше, попробуйте решить для начала задачу, а потом сделаете полноценный ответ с кодом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через регулярные выражения отделить код от ссылки и отправить на проверку через API Discord'a. Бонусом проверка всех остальных гифтов.

```py
import requests

def quickChecker(nitro: str):
    url = f"https://discordapp.com/api/v9/entitlements/gift-codes/{nitro}?with_application=false&with_subscription_plan=true"
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:  # Если код рабочий
        return True

    else:                            # Остальные ошибки
        return False
```